# FOSSIL: file outside of checkout tree

Tags: fossil

As I understand the directories of each file fossil.exe, repository-file and files (to be versioned) can be in totally different pathes, is that right?

However, I get the following error:

> file outside of checkout tree: path_to_file\filename

My structure is as follows:

> FOSSIL\fossil.exe
>
> NewFolder\repo.fossil
>
> NewFolder\Subfolder\sample_table.csv

When opening the repo and then running `fossil add full_path\sample_table.csv` I get the above mentioned error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things:

- It doesn't matter where the fossil executable is located, as long as it's somewhere in the search path (otherwise you have to use the full path every time).
- It doesn't really matter where the repository file is located either, as long as it doesn't move after you've opened it. (If you do want to move it, close the repository first).
- You're missing a *work directory*. You need to **open** the repository first, into a work directory (also called the *checkout tree*). That work directory will be where you'll be working on your files.

In the situation you describe, you'd need to run the following command:

```
cd <topmost folder of your code>
fossil open NewFolder\repo.fossil
```

After that, you can do whatever you need in that folder (and its subfolders), and anytime you perform a commit or checkin, the changes you've made will end up in the repository.

```
fossil add NewFolder\Subfolder\sample_table.csv
fossil commit --comment "Added sample table"
```

There's usually no reason to close the working directory again; except perhaps if you want to move the repository: you'd then use `fossil close` to close the working directory, move the repository, and then use `fossil open <new_repo_path>` from the working directory again.

Note that the repository can be located somewhere else entirely; and also that a single repository can be opened into several different work directories at the same time.

Comment: Thanks! I got it run. The clou is the `cd <topmost folder of your code>` which I thought has to be the folder of the fossil.exe.
Am I right, that the working directory (I think it´s the same given at local-root when calling status cmd) only depends on the path where the fossil.exe is called from?

Comment: Not quite. The [current working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory) is... whatever the current directory is when you call `fossil`. Do note that this is **not** necessarily the same as the "work directory" where you’ve opened a repository (aka the _checkout tree_).

Comment: having to close the repo first when moving is a hassle. WHy doesn't it use relative paths? What if I use a repo from a USB Stick where the path always changes? Yikes....

Comment: @xeruf That’s something you can ask the developers on the [Fossil Forum](https://fossil-scm.org/forum)...